# How to understand workflow of git submodule function

Tags: git, github, git-submodules

I'm working on git submodule as this:

1) create MASTER project git repo, do some commit

2) create SUB project git repo, do some commit

3) use git submodule function, add SUB into MASTER/somefolder/

4) Then Alice do 2 commit on SUB, branch Alice.

5) Then Bob do 2 commit, branch Bob.

6) Then I add Alice and Bob's commit into SUB and MASTER by submodule function.

---

In this process, I have some confuse:

1) In init process, which add SUB into MASTER, how will MASTER remember add commits in SUB?

For example, if SUB have 2 branch, which commits of branch will be remembered in MASTER?

If it's use SUB's master branch? Or use SUB's HEAD?

If use HEAD, then if I point HEAD into SUB's another branch (NOT master), what will happen?

2) When I add Alice's 2 commits of SUB into MASTER, how will MASTER know I want to add Alice's 2 commit, not Bob's?

As it's said MASTER do NOT care SUB's branch, only care SUB's commit.

---

This is my understand of implementation of git submodule function:

MASTER only remember ONE commit id like abcdefg123456.

Then if you do `git submodule update --init --recursive`, MASTER will download all commits in the branch of abcdefg123456 located, until abcdefg123456 commit.

Is it right?

---

If above is right, then I'm confused, branch Alice and Bob all add commits, If I use abcdefg123456 in Alice, then how to add Bob's commits?

Answer (score 0):

Main git repository (MASTER) and its submodule (SUB) are to be considered as **independents repositories**.

You may already know that once you *cd* in any SUB directory (or subdirectory), all git commands apply to SUB (and only to it). Then if you *cd* back into any MASTER directory (that is not any other submodule dir), all git commands refer to MASTER.

So you're right, the only thing MASTER remember about SUB is **remote address** and a **single sha1 reference** (and no branch name or tag name).